# Starting something once in OnCreate - Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio, oncreate

I found one topic with an answer, but I don't really know if it's a good solution. I need to connect with a server when user opens my app - and do it ONCE, not always when he press 'back button' and comes back to the 'main class'.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

    makeConnection = new MakeConnection(this);
    makeConnection.start();
}
```

Already tried initializing it within a constructor - but when it's fired I don't have variables yet (they're null).

I just want to create MakeConnection object and start it once per app.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Store a boolean value in SharedPreferences. Set it to true after the first time then check in onCreate()` if it has ever been run. This has been asked many times

Comment: That's what I've found but I don't know if it's 'professional'?

Comment: It's 'professional'. Go ahead and do it

Comment: Seems like you are looking for `Application#onCreate`

Comment: Simply Create a boolean variable and using shared preference save it as soon as you connect to server. Next time you can access that variable to check whether you are connected or not.
Create an if - condition and use  connection code inside it.